Non deterministic results with MariaDB CTEs
I am writing a query that makes use of random functions that essentially boils down to the example below:
with test_a as (
    select 
        rand()
), test_b as (
    select
        *
    from 
        test_a
)

select
    *
from
    test_a
    
union all

select
    *
from
    test_b

With this code, I get two different results for the random value, i.e:
0.013195173827181732
0.4233234193393247

This behaviour seems bizarre to me, why does the result of test_a not persist across other queries? Does this mean that test_a is being executed twice? I thought the point of CTE's was to encapsulate a result for simple & fast referencing in later SQL & so it didn't create a performance hit if it contained complex code. If it is executing twice, how is it any different to copy & pasting a subquery?
I am coming from a Postgres background and for my sanity I tested the exact same code (switching rand() to random()) and got back a result that I expected:
0.1106535559017996
0.1106535559017996

Any help would be much appreciated - is there any way I can configure the server/query to be deterministic?

Can you try set @@optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF' and re-test the query in that session?

I suggest that most people want RAND() to return a different value every time.

not much help but I know but works fine in mysql https://dbfiddle.uk/GcYTahPq what version of mariadb are you on?

'works' in postgresql https://dbfiddle.uk/CJq3iSKq but not sqlserver https://dbfiddle.uk/qm4L5ydX

What would you expect for a next value for a sequence? (instead of rand)

I'd say consider cte as a temporary view. You can reference it several times from your query. Let the optimizer decide if the result can be re-used or not.

@jarlh I think many think of it as a temporary table, not a temporary view, so it creates a snapshot of the results.

@Barmar, apparently some dbms vendors do the same...

@jarlh I wonder if the SQL spec doesn't say how non-deterministic CTEs should be handled, so it's an implementation detail.

@Barmar, I'm reading it right now, but that document is so time consuming to read. I haven't find anything about this yet.

Please do provide output of select version();

Hi all, sorry for the delay - timezone fun. My MariaDB version is 10.6.18-MariaDB-log & @@optimizer_switch does not seem to affect the result

@jarlh In my actual implementation I have a long and complex process that uses rand() along the way. I was treating the CTE as a temp table because I never considered that it would be executed multiple times if the optimiser chooses. I think I will probably just have to make use of temp tables to avoid any possible non-determinism.

I prefer logic that every select participating in UNION is an independent object. The final result is the series of those independent resultsets. So, I prefer different results in both cases with or without cte.
However, different db engines - different results ...
MySQL, SQLite and Postgres treats these two commands (with and without CTE) differently...
Oracle, MariaDB and SQL Server treats them the same, as independent, resulting differently with every execution.
Updated  answer
You could make sure that rand() will be executed once and the value returned could be the same using any kind of row generation ...
One of the options could be cross join like this ...
WITH
  test_a as ( select  rand() as rnd ), 
  test_b as ( select  *  from  test_a )
select   test_b.*  from  test_b
cross join ( select 1 as rn Union All Select 2 ) rn




rnd




0.8063967328578203


0.8063967328578203



... OR this ...
WITH
  test_a as ( select  rand() as rnd ), 
  test_b as ( select 1 as rn Union All Select 2 )
select   test_a.*  from  test_a
cross join test_b 




rnd




0.7863214256114526


0.7863214256114526



fiddle

@JonasMetzler  Just updated the answer.  Left just a bit of whataboutism to show that differences are not just between MariaDB and Postgres.

Great, I like this answer much more (upvoted) than before, it shows an option now how to solve the issue.

@JonasMetzler as OP, used to Postgres, expected two identical values, I, used to Oracle, expect (and prefer as said in the answer) two different values from the same sql. For me the issue is in the sql. The MariaDB engine works as it works. I don' t know the setup option to make it work like Postgres. So, the solution is in workarounds. One is in the updated answer. BTW did you ever union two queries that each of them results exactly the same ?

I can't remember to have done so, would likely just have build the random value in my application. But I don't know their use case. And you might call it a workaround, but I think you showed an option how to get what they want and don't see anything wrong with your approach.
